# ggplot Bar Plot semantics

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I am trying to use ggplot in Python for the first time and the semantics are completely unobvious to me.

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns: `date` and `entries_sum`. What I would like to do is plot a bar plot with the `date` column as each entry on the `x-axis` and `entries_sum` as the respective heights.

I cannot figure out how to do this with the `ggplot` API. Am I formatting my data wrong for this?

Comment: Need more information to give a good answer, e.g. what code did you try for your plot, and what was the result/error.  Also, have you looked at the [ggplot docs](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/how-it-works.html)?

Comment: Yes, I have. The issue (as mentioned below) was that I thought `'identity'` was the default parameter for `stat` for `geom_bar`. However, it doesn't work without it explicitly stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
ggplot(aes(x='date', y='entries_sum'), data=data) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Comment: So, this was it, obviously. I thought that `'identity'` was the default parameter for `stat`, so I had not put it in any of my attempts.

Comment: Indeed the documentation for the Python version of ggplot is not mature yet so takes a little testing to get it right.